# Updated to Debian 11 (Bullseye) and to latest kernel and now everything network related is very slow

Tags: ssh, debian, performance, internet

I updated to Debian 11 for some days ago as well as I installed a new kernel (5.10.28-1) and the system is working fine. However I noticed that everything network related is extremely slow. Trying to perform an apt update takes like 20 seconds to resolve the hosts. Adding a repository takes like 30 seconds. I have only tried the system over SSH if that makes any difference. I havent noticed any other issues but its really annoying if i.e. I need to update a server package and I need 40 minutes instead of 15. Any ideas why this is happening?

The login to SSH is as fast as usual but it looks like that the commands are not executing fast enough? like even running a shell script that will just display a message, take some seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course the solution was simple. The /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf was injecting some strange name servers in the resolv.conf. I removed them and everything started working perfectly fine again.